# Flask message flashing doesn't work with redirect

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to flash some messages when user signs up and then redirect to login page, but for some reason messages get lost. Strangely flashing message and redirecting when user logs in works. It also works if I `return render_template`

Here's my register route:

```
    @application.route('/register', methods=["POST"])
    def register():
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
    
        try:
            signup(conn, username.lower(), generate_password_hash(password))
        except psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation:
            flash("User already exists", "danger")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        
        flash("User created successfully", "success")
        return redirect("/login")
```

And after successful login this works:

```
flash("Welcome, " + user[1], 'success')
        return redirect("/")
```

Comment: Do your page templates all have the code to display flash messages?

Comment: Yes all templates extentending main layout.html, where is message container. I can see empty messages element in dev tools